# Today, all of sudden I cannot add a column through odbc driver in qt on my access database

Tags: c++, sql, qt, ms-access, odbc

I'm using Qt 5.15.2 and I am currently writing an address application. (Replacing the old mfc tool). We are storing the address data in a ms access database.

Yesterday I wrote the code to add a column to store an company icon. It worked perfectly. I testet it several times. No problems at that time. After work I shut down my notebook. Today I tried this once more and all of sudden it doesn't work anymore.

Here are some details:

```
openDatabase();

int iFind = kkp::DaoFindField(m_pDb, "Adressen", "Icon");
if (iFind < 0) {
    kkp::CDaoTableDef td(m_pDb);
    td.Open("Adressen");
    td.CreateField("Icon", kkp::DataTypeEnum::dbText, 0);
    td.Close();
}
```

The openDatababase function looks like this:

```
void KKP_Adressen::openDatabase() {
QString sFilename = m_sAppPath + "/Adressen/Adressen.mdb";
m_pDb = new kkp::CDaoDatabase();
bool bOpen = m_pDb->Open(sFilename.toStdWString().c_str());
Q_ASSERT_X(bOpen , "KKP_Adressen::openDatabase()" , "unable to open database"); }
```

Don't get confused by all that Dao namings originally comming from mfc. The plan is to not have to rewrite all the systems that use the address tool but only change the internal function of that library. I tried even that and it works. And don't get confused by this string conversions. It's because this is a lib that exports functions and classes useable for standart (neutral) c++ so that mfc and qt may use it. But internally I have to make several conversions therefore.

The creation of the column is actually quite simple: Create an QSqlQuery and execute the statement

```
QSqlQuery q(*db);
QString sQuery = "ALTER TABLE " + QString::fromStdWString(m_sTblName) + " ADD COLUMN ";
        std::wstring sColDefinition = m_cols.at(i);
        sQuery += QString::fromStdWString(sColDefinition);
if (!q.exec(sQuery)) {
            QString sErr = q.lastError().text();
            Q_ASSERT_X(false, QString::fromStdWString(__FUNCTIONW__).toStdString().data(), sErr.toStdString().data()); }
```

The statement actually looks like this (copied from the debugger):

```
ALTER TABLE Adressen ADD COLUMN Icon LONGTEXT
```

the error message looks like this (also copied):

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Das Datenbankmodul konnte die Tabelle 'Adressen' nicht sperren, da sie bereits von einem anderen Benutzer oder Vorgang bearbeitet wird. QODBC3: Unable to execute statement
```

Which means like: I cannot open the database for altering because it is already used by someone else.

I didn't change the code in between the working status and the failing status. I can delete the actual mdb file and get it back from subversion. I can open it with access and alter it. There was no windows update or whatsoever. I am totally out of ideas, what could be wrong there...

Any ideas someone?

Comment: Why even bother with code to add fields? Open Access, open table in design view, add field.

Comment: this can't be done. This database comes by installation to every costumer. He can input his own adresses there. So I may not replace the mdb file, but have to alter it. and doing this manually for about 3000 costumers might become "challenging"

Comment: I just figured out, doing the exact same thing with another table in the database totally works. Sometimes I really get desperate on not understanding microsoft technologies.

Comment: How often do you call openDatabase() and when do you close it?

Comment: I checked that too. I open it once then immediatly try to add that column. No other process are using that. The strange this is. Doing this by mfc works. Adding a column with a different name works. Adding a new table with the "Icon" coumn works. And it worked when I first tried it out. I have never seen such a strange behaviour.